# derivatives $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sand is falling from a rectangular  box whose base  measures $40$   inches  by  $20$    inches  at a constant rate of $300$ cubic inches per minute. (Include units in your answers.)

a) How is the depth of the sand in the box changing?

Comment: Let $V=V(t)$ be the volume of sand in the box at time $t$, and let $z=z(t)$ be the height of the sand in the box at time $t$. We know $\frac{dV}{dt}$ and want $\frac{dz}{dt}$. Find a relationship between $V$ and $z$, and differentiate.

Comment: That is _such_ a descriptive title.

Answer (score 1):

Let be V(t) the volume of the sand. And D(t) the depth of the sand. L(t) and W(t) are the length and the witdth of the box.

Now we can build the total differential of V(t).

Then $dV=\frac{dD}{dt}\cdot dt+\frac{dL}{dt}\cdot dt+\frac{dW}{dt}\cdot dt$

L(t) and W(t) are independent from t. Thus $\frac{dL}{dt}$ and $\frac{dW}{dt}$ are both equal to zero.

$dV=\frac{dD}{dt}\cdot dt\Rightarrow \frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{dD}{dt}$

$D(t)=\frac{V(t)}{800}\Rightarrow \frac{dD}{dt}=\frac{dV}{dt}\cdot \frac{1}{800}$

We know, that $\frac{dV}{dt}=300$. Now you can conclude what $\frac{dD}{dt}$ is.

Answer (score 0):

The box 'floor' area is 20 times 40 equals 800 square inches. So 300cubic inch per minute divide by 800 square inches equals a filling rate of 0.375 inches per minute.